# How to paint instantly my canvas by overriding paint() method in AWR J2SE 5.0

Tags: java, canvas, awt, drawing

I am creating a game of connect 4 by using Java in the process of learning the language.

I did a small cell of connect 4 which is basically an extends of a Canvas where i paint each pixels in blue or in transparent color if it is in the radius of a disk.

The problem that i am having with my code is that the cell isn't painted immediately, i can see all pixels being colored one by one forming my cell after something like 6-7 seconds.

I'd like to draw such a cell to place these in a grid layout and forming my connect 4 grid.

What am i doing wrong ?

Tried to search internet for solutions but haven't found so far. I can't use SWING.

```
package Puis4;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Vue_Cellule_Grille extends Canvas {
    // Attributs
    int width;
    int height;

    // Constructeur
    public Vue_Cellule_Grille() {

    }

    public Vue_Cellule_Grille(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // Methodes

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // TODO : Afficher lorsque c'est peint.

        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        int centreX = width/2;
        int centreY = height/2;
        Double diametre = this.getWidth() * 0.80;
        Double rayon = diametre/2;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                    Double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centreX-i, 2.0) + Math.pow(centreY-j, 2.0));
                    if (distance > rayon) {
                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    } else {
                        // Le constructeur prends les valeurs RGB en float et pas en double. 
                        g.setColor(new Color((float) 1.0,(float) 1.0, (float) 1.0, (float) 0.5));
                    }

                    g.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
package Puis4;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

public class Vue_Plateau extends Frame {
    // Main de Test

    public Vue_Plateau() {
        super("Cellule Grille du Plateau");
        this.setBounds(600, 600, 300, 300);
        this.addWindowListener(new Controlleur_Fermer_Plateau(this));

        // Layout & composants
            Vue_Cellule_Grille v = new Vue_Cellule_Grille();
            this.add(v);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

```
package Puis4;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Vue_Plateau();
    }
}
```

I'd like my extended canvas to be drawn exactly as i did in the paint method as soon as i am calling it to put it in a GridLayout or any LayoutManager.

Answer (score 0):

You must have something that tells AWT that the GUI needs to be repainted.
I can't tell you where to do this since you only showed us a fragment of your code.